# How to synchronize the data from server database to local database

Tags: ios, objective-c

I made an application. It contains some set of words. If I click any word, I am having two buttons: one is "add to favorites" and other is "My favorites". When I click "Add to favorites" the word will go to local database & server database as well and when I click the "My Favorites" button the word will come from local database. This is working fine.

Now, my problem is whenever I reinstalled the application when I click the "My Favorites" button, the words which are sent to server database should come and be synchronized in the local database so that I can have my favorite words again.
Please provide any logic regarding this. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Logic: `tr [[:upper:]] [[:lower:]]`...

Comment: I didn't Understand. Please explain clearly @H2CO3

Comment: @userXXX No need to yell in ALL CAPS.

Comment: what's the solution for my above problem ? @H2CO3

Answer (score 0):

Use AFNetworking, it's the best way for communicating with a server.